# Vue drag & drop in Recursive component & recursive nesting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Im working with Vue to create recursive Tree component, 
currently I have added support for checkboxes and expanding nodes, but Im having a bit of trouble with building drag & drop in recursive component

Is there any way to implement drag & drop with this sample:

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-brook-qcsh3)

I can get node that is dragged but on drop I do not get destination node ?
On Drag stop I only get dragged node, Should I add on some more places listeners ?

Here I only get dragged node ?

```
 handleDragEnd() {
          this.$el.classList.remove('cmp-drag-node');
      },
```

Note: **I do not want a solution with VueDraggable Im looking for a simple jsfiddle or some clarification on matter, Vue draggable wont work since I need to drop into the Node not only reorder nodes**

Comment: Vue Draggable supports nested stuff - this won't work? https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/nested-example

Comment: @Adam It is not working as expected I need to be able to put nodes into nodes that have nested children, but that is not working :/

Comment: ok, but rather than reinvent cue draggable because you can’t figure it out, you should probably use the library. Why don’t you show your attempt with it and we can help debug

Comment: @Adam I have updated link here it is to support VueDraggable, but I need to be able to put node inside other node(if that node is folder), https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-brook-qcsh3

Comment: Can you please add some of your code to the question?

Comment: @maxshuty there is  a codesandbox link

Comment: @Loki it helps to include it in the question itself as links to external sources may go dead over time. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @maxshuty It is included into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the Following codepen works fine for me. Managed to handle drag and drop with nested component but yah you need to change some code.

I have used `vuedraggable`. The main component is `Tree.vue` and the nodes are in the `Treenode.vue`. Sometimes it's cloning the node may bi I have missed something but yah everything else is working fine.

Codepen - https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-surf-ckv3y

Comment: Looks like sometimes is creating duplicated nodes

Comment: Yes looking into it but everything else is working fine.

Comment: Thank you so much , but the main problem I was having is to drop node into folder :/, I had other cases figured out, thats why I wanted custom solution without draggable

Comment: drop node into folder means?

Comment: Option to Drop node into Node that has subnodes